# Google Spreadsheet Query blanks out text cells in the query range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

When I perform a query to essentially filter a range of names, and times, any cell that is not a time gets blanked out. Screenshot of example:

[image]

I'm keeping this post fairly short since the image succinctly describes the problem. Whats causing this, and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUERY result assigns a data type to each column. The "blanked out cells" occurs because their data type is not compatible with the data type of the resulting column.

Instead of QUERY use [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).

To learn more about QUERY see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en and 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage.

Comment: In this case, I'm querying an import range as a single formula. Can I filter an import range without having to import the range multiple times within the filter formula?

Comment: Please post a new question with the corresponding details.

Comment: That seems like a waste, to post an identical question with the addition of a single sentence, barely changing the meaning of the question. Is your answer the only possible solution for the problem this question poses? If it isn't, then adding addition details would make sense wouldn't it?

Comment: A workaround would be never put any text in your original data. Instead, for "OFF", simply put a 0 value, and then use custom number formatting: `h:m am/pm;;OFF;@`