# Can I filter or query an IMPORTRANGE in a single formula without importing the range multiple times or using a second worksheet?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want to do this without using a second worksheet to hold the imported range. 
ie. `Filter(myimportRange, importrangepart = mycondition)`  since this has to import the range twice.

I also cannot seem to query the IMPORTRANGE since this results in blank cells as seen here:

[image: WA90350 question example]

Can I filter an IMPORTRANGE in a single formula without importing the range multiple times in the filter?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90343/google-spreadsheet-query-blanks-out-text-cells-in-the-query-range

Comment: Why importing a range twice or using a 2nd spreadsheet is a problem? Did you already tried to convert the time column to text or to use Google Apps Script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using FILTER or IMPORTRANGE to bring in and filter data from another spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87272/using-filter-or-importrange-to-bring-in-and-filter-data-from-another-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I filter or query an IMPORTRANGE in a single formula without importing the range multiple times or using a second worksheet?

Yes.

For example if you happened to have in Sheet1 of a document:

[image: WA90350 first example]

then this formula in F2 of the same sheet:

```
=query(importrange(" k e y ","Sheet1!A:D"),"select * where Col3 = 'Client 1'")
```

would return:

[image: WA90350 second example]

provided you use the appropriate `k e y`.